# Degrees conversion isn't working with inverse trignometry

Tags: javascript, html, trigonometry, inverse, degrees

I'm creating a calculator strictly using JavaScript and I found myself with a problem while creating the inverse functions of the trigonometry stuff. Everything worked while using radians, but in degrees, I got the wrong answers.

I wish it was as simple as my conversions being wrong, but everything else using degrees (i.e. the non-inverse trigonometry stuff) was working perfectly. The following code are the parts of the calculator that have any relationship with the degrees conversion and the trig stuff.

CODE SNIPPET:

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var degVal = true;
        var Deux = false;
        function toDegrees(angle, mode){ //This function converts radians to degrees, and vice versa
    if (degVal == true){
      mode = (Math.PI/180); //for some reason this incorrect conversion formula spits out the correct answers
    }
    else if (degVal == false){
       mode = 1;
    }
    return angle * mode;
    }
  function BasicTrig(TrigFunc, TrigInv){
    var val1 = toDegrees(parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value));
    var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
          if (Deux == false){
      ansD.value = TrigFunc(val1);
    }
    else if (Deux == true){
            ansD.value = TrigInv(val1); //For some reason, doesn't work in degrees
          }
  }
     function MoreTrig(TrigEq, TrigEqInv){ // This function allows csc, sec, & cot to be performed
    var val1 = toDegrees(parseFloat(document.getElementById("value1").value));
    var ansD = document.getElementById("answer");
    if (Deux == false){
      ansD.value = 1 / TrigEq(val1);
    }
    else if (Deux == true){
            ansD.value = TrigEqInv(1 / val1); //Also doesn't work in degrees
          }
  }
        function Deuxieme(){ //2nd function (Calculator) button
          if (Deux == false){
            document.getElementById("LeDeux").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
   Deux = true;
   document.getElementById("sinbutton").value = "sin⁻¹"; //changes sin to sin⁻¹
   document.getElementById("cosbutton").value = "cos⁻¹"; //changes cos to cos⁻¹
   document.getElementById("tanbutton").value = "tan⁻¹"; //changes tan to tan⁻¹
   document.getElementById("cscbutton").value = "csc⁻¹"; //changes csc to csc⁻¹ csc being cosec for those who are used to that
   document.getElementById("secbutton").value = "sec⁻¹"; //changes sec to sec⁻¹
   document.getElementById("cotbutton").value = "cot⁻¹"; //changes cot to cot⁻¹
          }
    else if (Deux == true){
            document.getElementById("LeDeux").style.backgroundColor = "";
      Deux = false;
   document.getElementById("sinbutton").value = "sin";
   document.getElementById("cosbutton").value = "cos";
      document.getElementById("tanbutton").value = "tan";
      document.getElementById("cscbutton").value = "csc";
         document.getElementById("secbutton").value = "sec";    document.getElementById("cotbutton").value = "cot";
          }
  }
        function RadDegHighlight(){ //Switches between Radians and Degrees
    if (degVal == true){
      document.getElementById("drbutton").value = "rad";
   degVal = false;
    }
    else if (degVal == false){
      document.getElementById("drbutton").value = "deg";
      degVal = true;
    }
  }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
   <input type="text" placeholder="x" style="width:48.5%" id="value1"/>
   <input type="button" id="LeDeux" style="width:23.5%" value="2nd" onclick="Deuxieme()"/>
    <input type="button" id="drbutton" style="width:23.5%" value="deg" onclick="RadDegHighlight()"/>
    <input type="button" id="sinbutton" style="width:23.5%" value="sin" onclick="BasicTrig(Math.sin, Math.asin)"/>
    <input type="button" id="cosbutton" style="width:23.5%" value="cos" onclick="BasicTrig(Math.cos, Math.acos)"/>
    <input type="button" id="tanbutton" style="width:23.5%" value="tan" onclick="BasicTrig(Math.tan, Math.atan)"/>
    <input type="button" id="cscbutton" style="width:23.5%" value="csc" onclick="MoreTrig(Math.sin, Math.asin)"/>
    <input type="button" id="secbutton" style="width:23.5%" value="sec" onclick="MoreTrig(Math.cos, Math.acos)"/>
    <input type="button" id="cotbutton" style="width:23.5%" value="cot" onclick="MoreTrig(Math.tan, Math.atan)"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Answer" style="width:100%" id="answer"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I assume the problem is somewhere in `toDegrees`, since everything else works in radians... about the `Math.PI/180` for the radians to degrees conversion, as I said before, it works everywhere else, and I even tested it out and it just messes all of the other calculations up and doesn't fix the current problem.

I've tested all of the other calculations and they are correct. Again, everything in radians works, but the inverse functions do not work for degrees, but the normal functions do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re converting the input of an inverse trig function from radians to degrees, but it’s not in radians in the first place. You need to convert the output when using the inverse.

Comment: If you mean to do `toDegrees(Math.asin(val1))` I've already tried that (and even meant to mention it in the question but I forgot), still doesn't work. For example, `toDegrees(Math.asin(.5)) = 0.009138522593601258`, where it should be 30, and `toDegrees(Math.acos(.5)) = 0.018277045187202516` where it should be 60.

Comment: @Gnago: Your `toDegrees` function doesn't convert to degrees. Write a `function toDegrees(radians) { return radians * 180 / Math.PI; }` and a `function toRadians(degrees) { return degrees * Math.PI / 180; }`.

Comment: Yeah, that solved the problem, I avoided that entire because it worked everywhere else. Oh well, thank you for your help